# How to access an element in Self in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, self

I am new to iOS development.I am trying to debug an old iOS app, as I was debugging it, I found a variable that I want to use[image]

The highlighted portion at the bottom is the one I want to access. In the console, the compiler suggested `self.universalLookupViewModel->cardInfo.info[@"show_card"]` to access the value. I am not sure about the syntax of how to use this in Objective-C code to access the value.

Does anyone know what is the syntax of to access the show_card in objective-c code ?

Comment: What error do you get when you use what the compiler suggested? (e.g something like `NSString *valueWanted = self...;`)

Comment: Show the `@interface` definition of the `ULDeliveryInformation` class.  It might provide methods to access such information for you.  I don't think you should be digging around in the guts of a class in order to get what you want, as the implementation could change anytime you update the project dependencies.